# How can a make a tool optional? and have it run only if the parameters are filled?

Tags: python, arcpy

I am running several tools in an arcpy script.  At the end of the script, I want to give the option to change the projection with a Define Projection.  Only I don't want the tool to run if the user doesn't want it to run so therefore if there is no parameter inputted into the tool then it won't run.

Is this possible?

I'm running ArcMap 10.5.  not sure what else you need to know.

```
Prjs = arcpy.GetParameter(4)
Prjs_List = []
for Prj in Prjs:
    if Prj not in Prjs_List:
        print Prj
        Prjs_List.append(dem)
if len(Prjs_List) == True:
    arcpy.DefineProjection_management(Cont_Cliff_Merged, Prjs)
else:
   arcpy.AddMessage("Define Projection tool Skipped.")
```

I was hoping this would create a list based off the input parameters and if there wasn't an input, the print statement would b displayed.

I get an error telling me the geoprocessing parameters are not iterable, meaning the .prj files can't be put into a list.

Thoughts?

Comment: "I get an error telling me the geoprocessing parameters are not iterable, meaning the .prj files can't be put into a list."

That is not what that error means. It just means that the object returned by `GetParameter()` is not iterable. You need to look at the object's properties to see which you want, see the code samples in the docs: http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/functions/getparameter.htm

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the GetParameterAsText() function instead. This way, if the input is empty it will return an empty string, otherwise it will return an string. If the input parameter accept multiple inputs, than you need to use split() function to split the multiple input into a list of strings.

Ie.:

```
Prjs = GetParameterAsText(4)
Prjs_List = Prjs.split(‘,’)
If len(Prjs_List):
Do something
Else:
Do otherthing
```